# Ejecting from Create React Native App as one of CI step

Tags: react-native, mobile, gitlab, expo

I created some POC for application in React Native.

I used create-react-native-app as the base for it. It's wrapped with Expo app.

Now I need to create some pipelines for it. I am using Gitlab as my CI.

I suppose that I should eject this application from Expo. But app's development with Expo is really good, I can quickly debug many things there and I have many things out-of-the-box.

How I should create whole flow if after ejecting I need to test it and deploy to Google Play/App Store?

Is it possible to eject this app as the CI step?

Answer (score 1):

There’s no need to eject your app, if all you want is to deploy it to Google Play and Apple App Store. To do this you can use Expo to [build a standalone app](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html). The Expo CLI includes commands you can use to build your app to get the .apk and .ipa files for deploying it to the stores.

Comment: Hi @fson, thank you for your reply! For a first step it's amazing. But... for now I won't do anything, but in the next iteration of my work I'd like to do some steps with testing etc and I'll need just built application.

Comment: You can integrate Expo standalone builds as a part of your CI step. See this blog post about how to use it in build automation: https://blog.expo.io/automating-standalone-expo-app-builds-and-deployments-with-fastlane-exp-and-exptool-9b2f5ad0a2cd

Comment: Thank you so much @fson. But I see that Expo apps are really huge (25MB+). I'd like to eject it before pushing to App Store/Google Play because I'd like to have smallest app as possible. Is this method pushes ejected app?

Comment: Currently the standalone apps built with `exp build` include all the Expo APIs. However, addressing this is on our roadmap: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/reducing-app-size